# Google Apps Script: Is there a way to get ALL file permissions (permissions ids)?

Tags: google-apps-script, permissions, google-drive-api

Every Google Drive file has **permissions** like:

- writer
- commenter
- viewer
- ...

I can read permissions via `DriveApp.getFileById(file_id).getEditors()` or `.getViewers()`, but I don't get **permission ids** this way. Is there a way to get permission ids, **like you get them over Google Drive API**.

I also tried `Drive.Files.get(file_id).permissions`, but it returns `undefined`.

Comment: Note that the Apps Script `Drive` advanced service is v2, not the latest v3: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/list also note that the `File#permissions` property doesn't exist for a *Team Drive* file (as stated in documentation).

Comment: Because google apps script intellisense was giving me an option for permissions. I used it and there was no error it just returned undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@tehhowch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9337071/tehhowch) comment led me in the right direction. The solition is:

`Drive.Permissions.list(file_id)`

This way you get all permissions with id-s and everything like with Google Drive API.

Comment: Note that, in order to use this method, you need to authorize the Drive API in Advanced Google Services, along with enabling the Drive API on the associated Google Cloud Platform project